# Apply custom walker and custom ul class to specific menus in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am trying to apply a custom walker and class to specific menus.
This is because my class for the UL is different depending on menu locations.

I have correctly registered menu location in the backend, and applied each menu to their location (Contact to contact, About to about etc.)

This is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to target my menu

```
function my_custom_walker( $args ) {
$menu_locations = get_nav_menu_locations();

if ($menu_locations == 'contact') {

$args['walker'] = new sidemenu_walker();
$args['menu_class'] = 'mycustomclassforul';

}
return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_custom_walker' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to do it with this

```
function my_custom_walker( $args ) {

$menu = $args['menu'];
if($menu->name = 'contact' || $menu->name = 'about' )  
{
    $args['container'] = '';
    $args['menu_class'] = 'mycustomclassforul';
    $args['walker'] = new sidemenu_walker();
}
return $args;

}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_args', 'my_custom_walker' );
```